# iOS: Cocoa Pods: Code Compile Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

**The Problem**

I recently started working on a project.

Which Uses Cocoa Pods as the dependency manager.

It also uses Crashlytics for crash reporting.

Image Magick for Icon generation and Synx for reorganizing the project folder.

I was given Git access.

So I cloned the repo.

did a `pod install`

and compiled the code but it started giving me following error.
[image: Error After Compile]

Project target is iOS 7.

Cocoa Pods Version is 0.36.4 also tried Latest 0.38.2

It is an iphone only app.

**What I have done So far trying to solve this issue**

So I sat down with the Original developer who was very helpful and had a working copy of the code on his machine. As it was a code handover so he was helping me setting it up on my machine.

We have tried all the usual suspects.

1. Clean and Build
2. Clean Quit Xcode Reopen and build
3. Quit xcode delete the Pods Directory and do a `pod install`
4. `pod setup`
5. `pod update`
6. Checked PODS_ROOT paths for different build configurations with working copy on another machine where it compiles correctly
7. My pods were latest so I uninstalled cocoapods using `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and installed the version the original developer had `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.36.4`
8. Matching Xcode versions xcode 6.4
9. Checking Configurations under Info in Project
10. Another pull from Github at a different location and doing all above steps.
11. Clear Xcode derived data folder.

So basically we checked all this retried all the above steps many times and also verified project settings build phases etc.

code is running fine on his machine.

Some weird behaviour i noticed was that one time instead of above mentioned error in picture it gave the famouse xyz.h file not found error for one of the libraries in Pods. But doing a `pod install` reverted back to original error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I remember this one.. I think it is due to cocopods changed the directory of there "copy pods resources" shell script from one version to the other. Look under your targets build phases and check for a "run script" entry i think. Look at the path and then check in finder to see where the shell script is really located.

Not really certain of the details... it might have been one of the other cocopods enters in the build phase section. Look around there, I do remember it was pretty easy to spot when you know where to look.

Should probably be the "Check Pods Manifest.lock" section under Build Phases.

Comment: I have this path

"${SRCROOT}/../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"

Same as original dev

Comment: How about the "check pods manifest.lock" section under Build Phases. How does that look?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are opening workspace project(.xcworkspace) instead of XCode Project..

Else

**Remove podfile.lock**

**Remove Pods Folder**

**Remove .xcworkspace**

**Remove manifest.lock (if exists)**

Go to path of pod file and Run **pod install**

Then it will generate .xcworkspace. 
Now onwards you need to use workspace instead of xcodeproj

[image: Manifest.lock]

[image: Run Script]

Hope it helps you..!